# Messages are gone when page refresh

Tags: pubnub

I am try to use this GitHub repo: https://github.com/jskrepnek/chatiNG

I adapted it to my website and everything is fine but except messages are gone when I refresh the page. I add `restore:true` to subscribe but that didn't work. My website is AngularJS based. So what causes this?

Comment: Provide your complete code (attached as zip file) and sub-key to support@pubnub.com and we'll take a look at it. Cheers, Craig

Comment: Also try `backfill:true` and see if that helps.  You ultimately want to use the `pubnub.history()` api for all messages.  You can also consider: http://pubnub.github.io/bootstrap-content-curator/

Comment: @Craig Conover Waiting response for the mail?